# Sending bcc email recipient in Jenkins using email-ext plugin

Tags: email, jenkins, email-ext, bcc

I am using the email-ext plugin in Jenkins to send email messages upon build completion in Jenkins.

I want to include certain email addresses as bcc and am using the following convention when specifying email addresses:

email1@domain1.com,bcc:email2@domain2.com,cc:email3@domain3.com

The first and last emails get sent correctly. However, the bcc email gets sent in the "To" section of the email with "b" prefixed to the address.
So instead of email2@domain2.com, it tries (unsuccessfully) to send an email to bemail2@domain2.com.

I looked at the email-ext issue list related to bcc and cc and did not find anything similar to this. Therefore I am posting it here.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Handling bcc was added in [this commit](https://github.com/jenkinsci/email-ext-plugin/commit/4aacabf9b9fa9be326ebc362519e2f5d1bbb43fb) on Feb 24, 2014, according to the changelog there was a [related fix](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin#Email-extplugin-2.40.3%28May20%2C2015%29) released as part of 2.40.3 on May 20, 2015.

So I would first check if you have at least this version installed and if not try to upgrade to the latest one to see if it works then.

Comment: Thanks. I checked and the version I am using is outdated. I will try and get the plugin updated to 2.40.3 or later and hopefully the issue will be resolved.